# Record audio from two different microphones at the same time using threads in java

Tags: java, multithreading, audio

I would like to build an application that records sound from two USB microphones at the same time and store each of the recordings in a different file. So far I have managed to build the application to suit only one microphone and it works fine. Its structure is the following:

- read a configuration file
- find all mixers that support recording
- select the desired mixer according to the configuration file
- record the audio from the desired mixer to a byte array
- write the byte array to a file

The first 3 steps appear in the application whether I want one or two microphones but I would like to start the recording for both microphones at the same time and also start writing each byte array on a separate thread as it is a bit time consuming and interfeering with the audio recording process, which is inside of a loop. This is what I have tried so far:

```
    recorder.readConfig(configFile);
    recorder.showAvailableMixers();
    recorder.selectMixer();
    while (true) {
        final byte[] audioBytes = recorder.recordAudio(recorder.firstMixer);
        new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                    final byte[] audioBytes2 = recorder.recordAudio(recorder.secondMixer);
                    recorder.writeToDisk(audioBytes2);
                } catch (InterruptedException | LineUnavailableException | IOException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(ContinuousAudioRecording.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }
        }.start();
        recorder.writeToDisk(audioBytes);
    }
```

This is a somewhat simplified version as it does not use another thread for writing to disk. I introduced the 1s sleep because the files to which I write have their names strictly dependent on the current time so I wanted to avoid an overwrite. The program that I have written here introduces a major delay between the 2 recordings and I was expecting them to record almost the same sound(with a 1s difference).

Can you please tell me what I am doing wrong or how should I approach this problem? I am new to using threads and I have spent all day long searching for tutorials and examples but I haven't yet found one to address the complexity of my program. Thank you!

**Edit on 25.08:** I have managed to solve the problem by creating another recorder object and do the same thing over again for it on another thread. It is not pretty and definitely not optimal but it is a work-around. I have also changed the method that was writing to disk so that now it is dependent on the microphone that is used for recording as well. Below you can find my new code if you wish to improve it or use something similar to this. Hope it will help someone in the future.

```
    final ContinuousAudioRecording recorder = new ContinuousAudioRecording();
    recorder.setConfigPath(ContinuousAudioRecording.class.getResource("config.prop").toString().replace("file:", ""));
    recorder.readConfig(new File(recorder.getConfigPath()));
    recorder.showAvailableMixers();
    recorder.selectMixer();
    final ContinuousAudioRecording recorder2 = new ContinuousAudioRecording();
    recorder2.setConfigPath(ContinuousAudioRecording.class.getResource("config.prop").toString().replace("file:", ""));
    recorder2.readConfig(new File(recorder.getConfigPath()));
    recorder2.showAvailableMixers();
    recorder2.selectMixer();
    while (true) {
        new Thread(){
            @Override
            public void run(){
                try {
                    final byte[] _audioBytes = recorder.recordAudio(recorder.firstMixer);
                    new Thread(){
                        @Override
                        public void run(){
                            try {
                                recorder.writeToDisk(_audioBytes,recorder.firstMixer.getMixerInfo().getName().replace(" ", ""));
                            } catch (IOException ex) {
                                Logger.getLogger(ContinuousAudioRecording.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                            }
                        }
                    }.start();
                } catch (LineUnavailableException | IOException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(ContinuousAudioRecording.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }
        }.start();
        new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    final byte[] _audioBytes2 = recorder2.recordAudio(recorder.secondMixer);
                    new Thread(){
                        @Override
                        public void run(){
                            try {
                                recorder2.writeToDisk(_audioBytes2,recorder2.secondMixer.getMixerInfo().getName().replace(" ", ""));
                            } catch (IOException ex) {
                                Logger.getLogger(ContinuousAudioRecording.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                            }
                        }
                    }.start();
                } catch (LineUnavailableException | IOException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(ContinuousAudioRecording.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }
        }.start();
        Thread.sleep((recorder.recordingLength+1)*1000);
    }
}
```

I have added the last sleep so that the new recording will start after the previous one ended. I have also given it another second in between recordings because it takes a certain period of time until all these instructions are performed(not an entire second, but just to make sure). Otherwise it would try to open the same `TargetDataLine` that was not previously closed and resulted in an exception.

Comment: "The program...introduces a major delay..."  How big is "major"?  Is there any overlap at all between the two?  I don't recognize the API that you are calling, but if there is no overlap at all, then I would suspect the recordAudio() method of using some internal `synchronized` resource.

Comment: Well I have spotted a problem with the code as it starts the thread for the second recording just after the first array of bytes has already stopped recording. I will start two separate threads and start a separate recording in each of them and see how it goes.